# display images one by one in android

Tags: android, arrays

i would like to display the letters of my app one by one in splash screen.I have 2 arrays for that **drw** array that holds the images in the resource folder and **drw_icon** that holds the image vies and i coded something lik this:

```
     for(j=0;j<lend;j++)
    {           
        drw_icon[j].setBackgroundResource(drw[j]); //this line shows error
    }
```

where lend is the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use handler to postdelayed a runnable which performs setting of image.

```
final ImageView drw_icon[] = new ImageView[] {
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image5) };

    final int drw[] = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    long delay = 1000l;

    for (int j = 0; j < drw.length && j < drw_icon.length; j++) {
        final int position = j;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                drw_icon[position].setImageResource(drw[position]);
            }
        }, delay * j);
    }
```